# Errors when merging SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with dataset

Tags: r, merge, r-sp

I'm trying to merge a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with my data. I have a matching variable that I'm trying to match on. The data.frame is longitudinal, so there are three entries for each ISO (i.e., South Africa (ISO:ZAF) has rows for 2002, 2007, and 2013). I've tried it using `taRifx.geo` and `sp`, but both throw errors.

Here is the code and error for the `taRifx.geo` attempt. I'm not at all sure this is right because the `merge` documentation for this package is terrible.

```
elephCountries <- taRifx.geo::merge(SPDF=afCountries, df=elephMapData, by=ISO_A3)

Error in as.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

The confusion with the above error is that nowhere in the `merge` documentation does it ask for an `x` argument. It asks for `SPDF` and `df`. That's it.

And here is the code and error for the `sp` attempt. The documentation here is better, but I've been unable to find anywhere an explanation for the error.

```
elephCountries <- sp::merge(x=afCountries, y=elephMapData, by="ISO_A3", duplicateGeoms=TRUE)

Error: nrowBefore == nrowAfter is not TRUE
```

I have searched all over for what this means, and am unable to figure it out. I honestly don't care which package I use to merge the two datasets, I just want it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here are the files that I'm trying to merge.

[The data file is here.](https://github.com/ldlathrop/Elephant-data-analysis/blob/master/Data/elephByCountry_master.xlsx)

[The map JSON file is here.](https://github.com/ldlathrop/Elephant-data-analysis/blob/master/Data/geo-countries-master/data/countries.geojson)

I'm subsetting only African countries as this is a project about the illegal killing of elephants. So here is the code:

```
countries <- readOGR("Data/geo-countries-master/data/countries.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")

afCountries <- subset(countries, countries$ISO_A3 %in% c(
"AGO", "BDA", "BEN","BWA","BFA","CMR","CAF","TCD","COG","CIV","COD", "COM",
"DJA", "DZA", "EGY", "ERI", "ETH", "GAB", "GHA", "GIN", "GMB", "GNB", "GNQ", "KEN", 
"LSO", "LBR", "LBY", "MDG", "MRT", "MUS", "MAR", "MWI", "MLI", "SDN", "SSD",
"MOZ", "NAM", "NER", "NGA", "RWA", "SEN", "SHN", "SLE", "STP", "SOM", "SWZ", "ZAF", "TZA",
"TGO", "TUN", "UGA", "ZAF", "ZMB", "ZWE"))

elephMapData <- read.xlsx("Data/elephByCountry_master.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")

elephCountries <- sp::merge(afCountries, elephMapData, by.x='ISO_A3', by.y='ISO3', duplicateGeoms=TRUE)
```

As I said above, I've tried merging with both the `sp` package and the `taRifx.geo` package and I'm getting the same error with both (i.e., `Error: nrowBefore == nrowAfter is not TRUE`). I've looked at the `sp::merge` code and it looks as though the number of rows for each file are supposed to match. However, it seems that with the `duplicateGeoms` call, that shouldn't matter. Here is what the `help` says about that:

```
duplicateGeoms  
logical; if TRUE geometries in x are duplicated if there are multiple matches between records in x and y
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to add attribute data to your polygons? Or are you simply trying to add more polygons? Using `merge` with spatial data is probably not a great idea. You should use a function from an actual spatial package, like rgeos, raster, sp, spatstat, maptools.

Comment: Can you post your shapefile and your data? It's easier to demonstrate the merge with actual data.

Comment: .@Tbar, thanks, and yes, I am trying to add attribute data so that I can use the data and maps with `leaflet`. Also, I actually am using the merge functions in spatial packages, as you can see from my code, i.e., `sp::merge(...)`. And @Phil, I've posted links to my data and GEOJSON files on Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is join your data (the `.xlsx` file) to the `@data` frame in the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object. The problem is this expects one row per country (which is how the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object is set up) but the data for each country is spread over three rows per country (one for each year).

I would suggest the best thing to do is munge the data into a format compatible with the spatial data. I would approach this by making a copy of the data frame and subsetting columns that are constant across all years (like the country name, region, latitude, longitude, etc.):

```
df <- elephByCountry[, c("region", "subregionid", "country", "ISO2", "ISO3", "cap.lat", "cap.long")]
df <- unique(df)
```

This gives you something you can merge back into the spatial data once you're ready. For each of the remaining variables that vary I would use the `reshape2` package to 'cast' the data into a tidy form. Using `Diff.from.expected` as an example:

```
library("reshape2")
dfe <- dcast(elephByCountry, ISO3 ~ year, value.var = "Diff.from.expected")
colnames(dfe) <- c("ISO3", "2002_diff.from.expected", "2007_diff.from.expected", "2013_diff.from.expected")
```

You can then merge these into the spatial data with `merge` or `dplyr::join()`. Using `merge()` as an example:

```
countries@data <- merge(countries@data, dfe, by.x = "ISO_A3", by.y = "ISO3")
```

Once you've done this for the variables you need (replacing `value.var =` as needed) and merged these into the spatial data, you can merge the 'constants' back in:

```
countries@data <- merge(countries@data, df, by.x = "ISO_A3", by.y = "ISO3")
```

From here you can plot your choropleth map:

```
library("maptools")  # needed for plot methods
plot(countries, asp = 1, col = countries@data$`2007_diff.from.expected`)
```

Comment: .@Phil Thanks so very much! This makes perfect sense.